# Using $this with Ajax call success handler

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a list generated with PHP that looks like the HTML code below. My AJAX call is completing successfully, the problem is my status message is only displayed for the first `div` in the list and I want it to be displayed based on which `input` box was clicked on. So I need a `this` reference to `#status_message` but I am not sure how to use it.

edit: changed id to class

HTML:

```
<input type='textbox' class='update'>
<div class='status_message'> </div>

<input type='textbox' class='update'>
<div class='status_message'> </div>

<input type='textbox' class='update'>
<div class='status_message'> </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.update').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url: '',
            dataType : 'json',
            data:  dataString ,
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#status_message').removeClass().addClass('error').text('There was an error.').show(200);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.error === true) {
                    $('.status_message').removeClass().addClass('success').text(data.msg);
                }
                else {
                    $('.status_message').removeClass().addClass('failure').text(data.msg);
                }
            } 
        });    
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements in a web page with the same id.

Comment: What @JayBlanchard said - change the id to a class and you are set.

Comment: changed to class still same issue.

Comment: @AmandaSky update your sample code to include your changes.

Comment: You still need a variable before the ajax function to referrence the element, and `$(this).next('.status_message')`, and live is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving the clicked element before calling your AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.update').live('click', function() {
        var status_message = $(this).next('.status_message');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url: '',
            dataType : 'json',
            data:  dataString ,
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                status_message.removeClass().addClass('error').text('There was an error.').show(200);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.error === true) {
                    status_message.removeClass().addClass('success').text(data.msg);
                }
                else {
                    status_message.removeClass().addClass('failure').text(data.msg);
                }
            } 
        });    
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store a reference to the element which was clicked on. Try this:

```
$('.update').live('click', function() {
    var $currentEl = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        // setup...
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var className = data.error ? 'failure' : 'success';
            $currentEl.next().removeClass().addClass(className).text(data.msg);
        } 
    });    
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    // setup...
    context: this,
    success : function(data) {
        var class data.error ? 'success' : 'failure';
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(class).text(data.msg);
    } 
});
```

*Reference*:

- [api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)